# error with INSERT due to subquery

Tags: sql-server, t-sql

I am setting up a job to transfer some data that is erased by the program that uses it so that we can keep the data longer and track it.

I get this error: "Column 'nextgen.ngprod.dbo.appt_slots.start_date' is invalid in the select list because it is not contained in either an aggregate function or the GROUP BY clause."

But when I add the group by i get the error: "Cannot use an aggregate or a subquery in an expression used for the group by list of a GROUP BY clause."

```
INSERT INTO [Analyst_db].[dbo].[appt_slot_util]
SELECT 
a.start_date,
a.Loc,a.Spec,
a.slots_avail,
a.slots_booked,
a.slots_open
FROM
(
SELECT asl.start_date
        , SUBSTRING(lm.location_name,6,2) as Loc
        , SUBSTRING(lm.location_name,9,3) as Spec
        , SUM(asl.overbook_limit) as slots_avail
        , SUM(asl.appt_count) as slots_booked
        , SUM(asl.overbook_limit)-SUM(asl.appt_count) as slots_open
FROM nextgen.ngprod.dbo.appt_slots asl
    JOIN nextgen.ngprod.dbo.location_mstr lm ON lm.location_id = asl.location_id
) AS a
WHERE NOT EXISTS
(
SELECT * 
FROM [Analyst_db].[dbo].[appt_slot_util] d
WHERE (
        a.start_date=d.start_date and
        a.Loc=d.Loc and
        a.Spec=d.Spec
        )
)
```

Comment: What is your interpretation of that very specific error message?

Comment: Please show your group by

Answer (score 1):

Looks like you are missing a group by in your subquery:

```
INSERT INTO [Analyst_db].[dbo].[appt_slot_util]
SELECT 
a.start_date,
a.Loc,a.Spec,
a.slots_avail,
a.slots_booked,
a.slots_open
FROM
(
SELECT asl.start_date
        , SUBSTRING(lm.location_name,6,2) as Loc
        , SUBSTRING(lm.location_name,9,3) as Spec
        , SUM(asl.overbook_limit) as slots_avail
        , SUM(asl.appt_count) as slots_booked
        , SUM(asl.overbook_limit)-SUM(asl.appt_count) as slots_open
FROM nextgen.ngprod.dbo.appt_slots asl
    JOIN nextgen.ngprod.dbo.location_mstr lm ON lm.location_id = asl.location_id
group by asl.start_date
        , SUBSTRING(lm.location_name,6,2) 
        , SUBSTRING(lm.location_name,9,3)  
) AS a
WHERE NOT EXISTS
(
SELECT * 
FROM [Analyst_db].[dbo].[appt_slot_util] d
WHERE (
        a.start_date=d.start_date and
        a.Loc=d.Loc and
        a.Spec=d.Spec
        )
)
```

Answer (score 0):

I found it out. I included too many values in the group by